# Unifi internet outside internal network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

We have internal network in our firm that shows the connected PC-s and printers and other devices. All the PC's have connection to the internet.
So for the needs of the firm my boss wanted wifi, and we have bought Ubiquiti UPD-AC-LR unifi. I'v installed the device and the wifi network is working perfectly. All the devices can be connected and use the internet from the device. But my boss wnat's to manage the wifi the way that no other devices and pc's to be visible for the people who are connected to the wifi network.
The one who connect to the Wifi, not to have access to the internal network of the firm. To have only internet and not to see the other computers and devices. Not to have access to them true the Wifi.

The model of the access point is Ubiquiti UAP AC LR. I'v manage to set it with the software from the official site here - https://www.ui.com/download/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lr i used the UniFi Network Controller 5.10.25 for Windows 10 to manage the device. And this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRE-EDYp1I8 . If there is a setting in the admin panel pls show me where to set it down or just explain to me what do i have to do. My boss what's it.

Thx in advance

Comment: Could you possibly redo this question as I can't quite understand it

Comment: Check it now - do you undearstand it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup a guest network on the controller, this will restrict all wifi users to internet only and they will not be able to see other devices. The unifi controller documentation has a section regarding this.